# how to convert Mongodb find({},{"array_field":1,"_id":0}) return into a 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, data-science, pymongo

I'm using MongoDB, in all my documents I have a field that is an array(all arrays same length), I want to retrieve all those arrays in one single 2d array, HOW?
my best effort was:
np.array(collection.find({},{"array_field":1,"_id":0})
but I'm getting pymongo.cursor.Cursor object

Comment: please, add example document and required final output

Comment: from pymongo's docs: "To get more than a single document as the result of a query we use the find() method. find() returns a Cursor instance, which allows us to iterate over all matching documents.". 

So just iterate over the cursor object.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `list(collection.find({},{"array_field":1,"_id":0})` to get a list of objects from the cursor. Then you can construct any object you like with that. Also you can loop over the cursor directly. Something like this should work:

```
myCursor = collection.find({},{"array_field":1,"_id":0}
myList = []

for item in myCursor:
   mylist.append(item["array_field"])
```